# Не работает кнопка при expand-collapse

Tags: bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#
    navbar"
    aria-controls="navbar"
    aria-expanded="false"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Dashboard <span
    class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#settings">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#help">Help</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </nav>
```

При разрешении меньше lg появляется кнопка , пытаюсь на неё нажать , но ничего не происходит
все link и script добавлены

Answer (score 0):

может чего не догоняю, но у тебя в коде так же перенос строки в data-target у кнопки ?)

Comment: Боже , спасибо .